# Create Sqlite3 database

Tags: sqlite

I am simply trying to create a database.

In my account's home directory, I type in

> sqlite3 test.db

Then once I am in sqlite, I type

> .quit

That **should** create the database file in the current directory.
But there is no such file!
I tried it in other directories (chmodded to 777) to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?
OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Sqlite version 3.8.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you haven't actually done anything.

Doing nothing:

```
phil@ironforge:~$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .quit
```

File not created:

```
phil@ironforge:~$ ls -al test.db
ls: cannot access test.db: No such file or directory
```

Do something:

```
phil@ironforge:~$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table a (b number);
sqlite> .quit
```

File has been created:

```
phil@ironforge:~$ ls -al test.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 phil phil 2048 Oct 21 09:31 test.db
phil@ironforge:~$
```

Comment: I've seen several tutorials that menioned the instructions in my original post. And I vaguely remember being able to successfully create empty databases in the past with this command. But your answer works - I have added a table and then removed it again to create a blank database.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an empty database with

`sqlite3 new.sqlite "SELECT 1;"`

A database is created and the result of the SELECT is printed, leaving just an empty database.

Answer (score 0):

you can just touch a database in GNU/LINUX families...

```
touch test.db
```

this would save time and you can open the database and edit it whenever you want. or read it's data from existing **.sql** file.